# Read cross-site cookie in with WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies, webdriver

Another WebDriver question.

How can I retrieve a cross-site cookie using WebDriver?

The architecture is like this:

1. User navigates to landing page: `https://landing.page`.
2. User makes login request to API gateway to `https://api.gateway`.
3. API gateway proxies request to backend, authenticates user.
4. API gateway responds to client with a `Set-Cookie` header with `jwt=abcd;samesite=None;secure;httponly;path=/`.
5. User continues to use cookie on all requests to API gateway.

Is there a way I can retrieve the cookie using WebDriver?
`driver.manage().getCookies()` yields no results and returns an empty set.

When checking manually with Firefox I cannot see the cookie either (which I assume is because I am on the wrong domain).